# How to add new fields to an Array of Objects, or insert values from one array to another - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a current Array of objects that looks like this:

```
this.subsidiaryOptions = [
  { label: FILTER_LABELS.topLevelOrganization, value: '0', selected: !this.includeOpportunities },
  { label: FILTER_LABELS.currentOrganization, value: '1', selected: !this.includeOpportunities }
];
```

now I have this new array like this one - i'm trying to add these fields as labels in the other array or adapt this array to be like the original one:

```
   this.engagementService.orgSubSidNames = 
   ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

I want to either make the current array include each member of this new arrays members in it's label field and then have the 'values' increase by 1 for each one, and add all of them have a 'selected' field.

Or add the fields into this new array, the array's size is not static either it will change.

I tried to use a push method with the labels like this:

```
    this.engagementService.orgSubSidNames.push.apply(this.engagementService.orgSubSidNames, this.subsidiaryOptions);
```

But couldnt get it to work, i was going to rap it in a for loop to increase the values but im getting an error on this push attempt.

expected result:

```
 Either array   = [
  { label: a, value: '0', selected: !this.includeOpportunities },
  { label: b, value: '1', selected: !this.includeOpportunities },
  { label: c, value: '2', selected: !this.includeOpportunities },
  { label: d, value: '3', selected: !this.includeOpportunities },
  { label: f, value: '4', selected: !this.includeOpportunities },
  { label: g, value: '5', selected: !this.includeOpportunities }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function namesAsOrgs({ includeOpportunities, orgSubSidNames }) {
  return orgSubSidNames.map((name, i) => {
    return {
      label: name,
      value: `${i}`,
      selected: !includeOpportunities
    }
  })
}

console.log(namesAsOrgs({
  includeOpportunities: true,
  orgSubSidNames: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
}))
```

Comment: Thank you Callam, I am trying to understand why the Curly braces were used inside of the functions parameters? something to do with destructuring objects?

Comment: This is interpolation – it's very useful when you need to plug a string with variables. In this case, we are simply interpolating the index to make it a string, but this could also be done with `'' + i`

Comment: I can't put the result into a variable though so I can actually use it? like:    var subSids = namesAsOrgs({
      includeOpportunities: false,
      orgSubSidNames: this.engagementService.orgSubSidNames
    })    just returns as an empty array, it consoles fine but I need to use it?